# Why is my switch case in java not compiling?

Tags: java, android, xml

These items that i started with are these. I was suppose to use them for a navigation bar and name them as following.

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_qr"
        android:title="QR Scanner"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_qr_code_scanner_24"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_students"
        android:title="Students"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_group_24"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_attendance"
        android:title="Attendance"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_list_24"/>
```

and then i tried to call them here but then the console says that the item with ids are not found.

```
binding.bottomNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_students:
                    replaceFragment(new StudentFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_attendance:
                    replaceFragment(new AttendanceFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_qr:
                    replaceFragment(new QRFragment());
                    break;
            }

            return true;

        });
```

they keep appearing in the console as errors when i try to run it saying:

```
Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\pc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:34: error: constant expression required
                case R.id.nav_home:
                         ^
C:\Users\pc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:38: error: constant expression required
                case R.id.nav_students:
                         ^
C:\Users\pc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:42: error: constant expression required
                case R.id.nav_attendance:
                         ^
C:\Users\pc\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\myapplication\MainActivity.java:46: error: constant expression required
                case R.id.nav_qr:
                         ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

It also says "constant expression required:(code line)"

Can someone point out how to fix these?

Comment: Google the error. `R.id.nav_` are not constants. Use an `if / else` chain instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With android gradle plugin 8.0+ resources are not final anymore. You can either use `if/else chain` (Alt+Enter on switch statement for Android Studio to automatically change it) or you can opt for old behaviour by adding

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

in your `gradle.properties` file